# How to show all the failed list item info with comma separated in a single alert?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am working on a Training application for our organization where trainings happen in many locations.
I am having a Employees column in my form where user can add multiple employees through peoplepicker. 
When a user add employee and submit, the system will check the employee details from "EmployeeInformation" list and then the information is saved in "Nominations" form. All the flow is working perfect but I am having a requirement where the employees whose location is not equal to training 
location, the alert has to be shown with all the employee names (refer onQuerySucceeded4).

For example A,B,C,D are entered as employees where B and C locations and training locations doesn't match then on submit the alert has to be shown as:
"The location of A, C doesnot match current training location".
Currently it is showing item by item. Please help.

Html:

```
<div id = "select_employees">
  <div>Employees</div><div style="margin-left: 66px;"><span class="pplCtrl" id="sp-ppl-Employee"></span></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Approve" onclick="addNomineeDetails();" /></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function addNomineeDetails() {

  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('EmployeeInformation');
  var arrFilter = [];
  var empForSearch = getUsersFromPicker('sp-ppl-Employee'); //sp-ppl-Employee is people picker id
  var empCaml = '';
  empForSearch.forEach(function(currentVal, index, arrVals) {
    if (currentVal && currentVal.IsResolved) {
      empCaml += '<Value Type=\'User\'>' + currentVal.DisplayText + '</Value>';
    }
  });
  if (empCaml != '') {

    arrFilter.push('<In>' +
      '<FieldRef Name=\'EmployeeName\'/>' +
      '<Values>' +
      empCaml +
      '</Values>' +
      '</In>');
  }

  var whereFilter = '';
  for (var i = arrFilter.length; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i == arrFilter.length) {
      whereFilter += arrFilter[i - 1];
    } else {
      whereFilter = '<And>' + arrFilter[i - 1] + whereFilter + '</And>';
    }
  }
  var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View>' +
    '<ViewFields>' +
    '<FieldRef Name=\'EmployeeName\' />' +
    '<FieldRef Name=\'EMPID\' />' +
    '<FieldRef Name=\'EMail\' />' +
    '</ViewFields>' +
    '<Query>' +
    '<Where>' +
    whereFilter +
    '</Where>' +
    '<OrderBy>' +
    '<FieldRef Name="EmployeeName" Ascending="False"/>' +
    '</OrderBy>' +
    '</Query>' +
    '</View>');

  this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
  clientContext.load(collListItem);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded4), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed4));
}

function onQuerySucceeded4(sender, args) {
  debugger;
  var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
  while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    emp_id = oListItem.get_item('EMPID');
    emp_name = oListItem.get_item('EmployeeName').get_lookupValue();
    user_email = oListItem.get_item('EMail');
    if (trainingLoc == empLocation) //here trainingLoc and empLocation are defined in previous functions
    {
      createMultilistItem();
    } else {
      alert('The location of ' + emp_name + ' doesnot match current training location.');

    }

  }


}
```

Comment: Please remove non-relevant code.

Comment: removed non-relevant code